# ¿Cómo acomodar datos para un gráfico de columnas apiladas?

Tags: powerbi

estoy intentando realizar un grafico de columnas que muestre tres datos distintos (Agua, Gas, Cloaca), los cuales tienen dos variantes de datos solamente (Accede, No accede) y un valor que refleja cantidades de personas para cada fila (Ponderación).

No me estaría saliendo acomodarlos en tres barras en un grafico de barras apiladas, y que cada una de ellas se dividan en sus respectivos dos colores para si acceden o no al servicio.

*Ejemplo de data*

| Agua | Gas | Cloaca | Ponderacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accede | No accede | Accede | 10.456 |
| No Accede | Accede | No accede | 8.229 |
| Accede | No accede | No accede | 5.546 |
| Accede | Accede | No accede | 11.323 |
| Accede | Accede | Accede | 9.992 |

Se agradece de antemano.

Comment: Intenta utilizar una tabla o matriz para visualización de tus datos.

Comment: Y para visualizarlos en un grafico de barras apiladas?

Comment: En este video creo que encontrarás lo que quieres buscar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aVCtjPZJsE